# What is the h function doing in THREE.WebGLUniforms?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on an optimization for a WebGL project that is basically just a frag shader attached to a quad that covers the canvas. The shader uses a rather expensive loop to cast rays through each pixel until they hit the some terrain. The idea is to, instead of calculating ray direction for each pixel, calculate the ray direction for each corner of the screen and pass them in as uniforms then interpolate between them based on uv's. I've tested this idea in the shader code without using uniforms, it works except for the fact that it slows it down instead of speeding it up.

When I try to load the web page when the whole thing with the uniforms is implemented, Firefox says that there is a type error, that `b` is not defined in three.js line 12914.

Going to line 12914 I've found:

```
h = function(a, b) {
  void 0 !== b.x ? a.uniform3f(this.addr, b.x, b.y, b.z) : void 0 !== b.r ? a.uniform3f(this.addr, b.r, b.g, b.b) : a.uniform3fv(this.addr, b)
},
```

inside `Three.WebGLUniforms`.

So my question is: what is this function for and what is it's second argument?

UPDATE:

An important detail that I left out is the fact that it crashes Firefox if I leave it open for more than a few seconds.

Comment: Step up the call tree with your debugger and see where it's called from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it is [this function](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/013b604d20ffc6f0bcd1b0ac36f2c755d9b851ba/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLUniforms.js#L169-L185).

It is a helper function to upload any uniform that will appear as `vec3` in glsl. This includes `THREE.Vector3`, `THREE.Color` and arrays with three elements. [See also](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/uniform).

So your "b is not defined" means that some uniform-value that should contain a vector, color or array was undefined instead. You should just have the debugger stop on exceptions and look at the stack to see which uniform that was.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the minified build of Three.js. Remove `.min.` from your threejs script name, for example use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.js` instead of `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js`. Only use the minified version for your production deploys, not for local development.

Comment: If this is where the error is coming from, won't it still be there when I switch back to the minified version?

Comment: I switched to the non-minified version and had the same problem except with a variable called `v`

Comment: Yes, it will still error, but it will have human readable code :)

Comment: I googled "why should i debug minified javascript files". :D

Comment: @AndyRay Oh i see why're you're suggesting this, its unnecessary because i already beautified the code with an atom plugin